# Counting a sum of a closed interval

Tags: java, loops, numbers

I'm currently learning Java through University of Helsinki's MOOC on Java and I'm stuck on an exercise about loops.

The exercise asks the user to input two integers which create a closed interval. The output should be the sum of the sequence of those numbers.

E.g.
First number is 3, last number is 5. The result of the sum would be 3+4+5=12.
My issue is that in the results only the numbers 4 and 5 were counted.
Here is my code:

```
public class SumOfASequenceTheSequel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("First number? ");
        int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Last number? ");
        int last = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        
        int n = first;
        int sum = 0;
        
        while (n < last) {
            n++;
            sum += n;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

    }
}
```

I tried altering the value of variable *n* as such:

```
int n = first - 1;
```

This allowed for the result of 3+4+5=12, but I figured that this was just a quick fix and it didn't really solve the root issue. Is there a way to include the first number in the loop so that the sum is shown properly? Any extra explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be a bit too early in your studies, but a powerful tool you can use to analyze issues in your code is a *debugger*. For instance, it allows you to step through your code while the program runs and see how the different variables change. Depending on which editor you use to write your programs, a debugger might even already be built in. But there's also debuggers you run from the command line - in case of Java, google "jdb". (However, the user interface of command line debuggers stem from ancient times, so that alone might be a bit off-putting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your loop: **first** it runs `n++`, and only then does it add `n` to sum.

Just reverse those two.

Or better yet, 'go from number A to number B' is textbook for loop:

```
for (int n = first; n <= last; n++) sum += n;
```

is all you need, and is 'idiomatic', in that this is what most java developers should do.

NB: Edited; evidently the question treats both numbers as inclusive, so `<=` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating loops like this (starting with `first-1` for example) is fine and often done.  But I think if you want a cleaner solution you should do two things.  First, don't increment `n` before you use it.  And second since you want the final value included in the sum, you should use `<=` rather than `<`.

```
    int n = first;
    int sum = 0;
    
    while (n <= last) {
        sum += n;
        System.out.println(n);
        n++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand requirements correctly

```
int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
int last = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

int sum = 0;
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    sum += i;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```